# How to have $anchorScroll only applied when mobile browser/device is Detected

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I was able to get the anchorScroll to work.

But I do have a question: Is it possible to only apply the anchorScroll when mobile device is detected. If so, how would I apply it to my controller?

The following section of my controller is where I display my result and where the anchorScroll is being applied:

```
$scope.SearchProvider = function(searchParam){
        try{
            $scope.searchMode = 1;
            var queryString='';
            if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
                $scope.resultsCount = 0;
                currentPage = 1;
            }
            if(searchParam){
                $scope.formModel = searchParam;
                for(var param in searchParam){
                    if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
                        var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
                        if (paramValue.length > 0)
                            queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
                    }
                }
            }
            //debugger;
            console.log(queryString);
            queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;

            $http.get("/includes/ReturnProvidersList.cfm" + queryString)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.providers = response.data.provider;
                $scope.resultsCount = response.data.rowCount;
                if (!$scope.providers){
                        $scope.NoResults = true;
                        $scope.ShowResults = false;
                        $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        $location.hash('error');

                        // call $anchorScroll()
                        $anchorScroll('error');
                    }
                else if($scope.providers){
                        $scope.NoResults = false;
                        $scope.ShowResults = true;
                        $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        $location.hash('ResultsAnchor');

                        // call $anchorScroll()
                        $anchorScroll('ResultsAnchor');
                    }
                else{
                        $scope.NoResults = false;
                        $scope.ShowResults = false;
                        $scope.ShowDesc = true;
                        $location.hash('noScroll');

                        // call $anchorScroll()
                        $anchorScroll('noScroll');
                }
            })
        }
        catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**The following is what I did per @BShaps suggestion. However, it is still being detected on desktop/laptop browser:

```
    $scope.providers = response.data.provider;
    $scope.resultsCount = response.data.rowCount;
        if (!$scope.providers){
                $scope.NoResults = true;
                $scope.ShowResults = false;
                $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                $location.hash('bottom');

            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) 
                            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) 
                            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){
                // call $anchorScroll()
                $anchorScroll('bottom');
            }
        }
        else {
                $scope.NoResults = false;
                $scope.ShowResults = true;
                $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                $location.hash('ResultsAnchor');
                if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) 
                            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) 
                            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){                            
                    // call $anchorScroll()
                    $anchorScroll('ResultsAnchor');}
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3rd party AngularJS library like the ngDeviceDetector. There is a very nice article describing it here: https://ciphertrick.com/2015/09/21/detect-os-browser-and-device-in-angularjs/.

Once you have injected the deviceDetector in your controller, simply wrap the $anchorScroll call in an if statement whose condition is based on the properties of the deviceDetector JSON object.

Comment: @ M.F. Thank You. I will look into this

Comment: @ M.F. Was not able to get this approach to work. Throws in error in the console regarding the script

Comment: @RobertoFlores, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @RobertoFlores It's very hard to say without seeing the actual error. Can you please paste it here?

Answer (score 1):

I run this check in some of my code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) 
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) 
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i))
```

No plugin required, but the list is possibly incomplete.  If you wrap the $anchorScroll inside that if statement you should be fine.

Comment: @ BShaps: I have tried implementing your code and it still effects both non and mobile devices

Comment: @ BShaps: Added what I did. I hope you con tell me what I am doing wrong